# Looking to add a bath fan

Tags: electrical, wiring, switch

I have a light that has power to it and then from there goes to a switch.  So neutral is hot back to light so you can turn it off and on.

Behind the switch in the box the power is split to 3 outlets.  I am getting rid of one of the outlets.  Is it possible for me to pull the wire from that outlet into the switch box to power a second switch for the fan?  So the power comes in from two lines but they are all the same breaker.  They will also be on separate switches.

Answer (score 1):

If i'm understanding you correctly, you have a light that has a power source coming directly into it.  From there, two wires go down to the switch (Black is power to the switch, and White is the power back up to the light.)  You have some outlets that come from the light junction box and want to remove one of them.  You want to add a second switch so that you can control a fan that you want to add to the light.

From this, it sounds like it is very possible.  It sounds like you just need one more wire from the switch(s) location back up to the light/fan.  You would use the power from the first switch to jumper over and feed the second switch.

**Edit**

In order to avoid having two power feeds coming into the same switch box, i suggest taking the cable that goes to the laundry outlet, and put it into the switch box.  This will gain the neutral as you mentioned and as gregmac mentioned about 404.2(c) requiring a neutral in the switch box.  So at this point you have two power feeds in your switch box.  Then go to the light fixture and disconnect the power feed that goes from the light directly to the switch box (black wire i believe).

Now you will have your power and neutral in one cable (from the laundry outlet) and then you will have a cable with one wire (white) acting as the switch-leg going back up to the light, and the other wire unused (black).

Comment: Because you need a wire between the existing light box and new fan (to get a neutral), and another wire between the switch and fan (for control), it would be better to just have a second switch loop from the fan, rather than jumpering the two switches together.  Note though that this setup doesn't get a neutral in the switch box, which is required in new construction (NEC 404.2(C)). How your local AHJ/inspector interprets this may mean a neutral should be added (easiest way would probably be to change to a 14/3 between fan and switch).

Comment: Well the fan and light are not going to be in the same place, light above mirror and fan on opposite side of room on ceiling. Correct there is no neutral in the switch box. By pulling the outlet from the laundry room I would gain a neutral for the switch box but still the issue of having 2 power lines into the switch box, one for each switch. The thing is though that both power lines will be off on the same breaker, is this legal? I do know you should not have 2 different breakers going into the same box but like I said these would be off the same breaker. Thanks.